# Overriden Virtual methods not being called

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino, abstract-class

I'm trying to create an abstract class that some other classes can be based off of for an arduino project. But, whenever I call a method that is virtual in the base, it just calls the base implementation. Code below. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
#define RTCBASE 0
class RTC_Base {
public:
  virtual uint8_t begin(void){ return 0; };
  virtual void adjust(const DateTime& dt){};
  virtual DateTime now(){ return DateTime(); };
  virtual int Type(){ return RTCBASE; };
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// RTC based on the DS1307 chip connected via I2C and the Wire library
#define DS1307 1
class RTC_DS1307 : public RTC_Base 
{
public:
  virtual int Type(){ 
    return DS1307; 
  }
  uint8_t begin(void);
  void adjust(const DateTime& dt);
  uint8_t isrunning(void);
  DateTime now();
  uint8_t readMemory(uint8_t offset, uint8_t* data, uint8_t length);
  uint8_t writeMemory(uint8_t offset, uint8_t* data, uint8_t length);


};

///In Code
RTC_Base RTC = RTC_DS1307();
DateTime dt = RTC.now();
//The above call just returns a blank DateTime();
```

Comment: Perhaps you're experiencing object slicing.

Comment: You are 1) defining the functions in the derived class and 2) not slicing, right? Also a class isn't abstract unless it has at least one pure virtual member function, which yours does not.

Comment: You'll have to show example of your usage. How is the class instance created, how is it turned into the base class, and how are you calling the function?

Comment: Sorry... example added.

What is Slicing?

Maybe abstract was the wrong term... I had trouble getting the compiler to be cool with pure virtual, so I took them out.

Comment: Partly, when I tried to use a pure virtual it would not let me do this: RTC_Base RTC; Which I would like to do so that I can decide which derived class to use at runtime.

Comment: @AdamHaile It's supposed to not let you do that. You aren't supposed to ever create *instances* of a pure-virtual class, only pointers or references. It's a safety feature.

Comment: That's what I thought... but maybe I've just been doing C# for too long. I'm used to just doing this:
Abstract a = new Derived();
a.AbstractMethod();
((Derived)a).DerivedMethod();

And it seems very happy to do so :P

Comment: In C++, that'd look like:
Derived derived;
Abstract &abstract = derived;
abstract.AbstractMethod();
derived.DerivedMethod();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the code:

```
RTC_Base RTC = RTC_DS1307();
DateTime dt = RTC.now(); //The above call just returns a blank DateTime();
```

That's [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (as @chris originally guessed). For [Polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) to work, you'll have to pretend your derived class is a base class, by treating a *pointer or reference* as a Base, when it really is the address of a Derived. (Because the Derived actually contains the Base within it).

```
Derived myDerived;
Base &myBaseRef = myDerived;

myBaseRef.myVirtualFunction();
```

Otherwise, you are creating a Derived, and trying to force the bytes into a Base, and losing all the Derived's bytes. It's not good! =)

The point is, you shouldn't actually be *converting* the Derived to a Base, just accessing the Derived as if it were a Base. If you convert it to a Base, it *is* a base. And your Base class returns an empty DateTime.

To do so with dynamically allocated memory, you can do this:

```
Base *myBase = nullptr; //Or 'NULL' if you aren't using C++11
myBase = new Derived;

myBase->myVirtualFunction(); //Dereference the myBase pointer and call the function.

delete myBase; //Free the memory when you are finished.
```

If you are using C++11, you can let [std::unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/?kw=unique_ptr) handle the lifetime of the object for you, so you don't have to remember to call 'delete':

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> myBase;

//Later...
myBase = new Derived;
myBase->myVirtualFunction();

//Automatically freed when the myBase smart pointer goes out of scope...
```

Comment: I *think* that makes sense...
Is there a good way to do that so that RTC_Base &RTC can be a global variable (and not set to something until the setup() method)? Also, is it possible to do this and still have the base contain pure virtuals?

Comment: I just get " error: 'RTC' declared as reference but not initialized
" when I try to make it global with no immediate init

Comment: Sure, use a pointer instead of a reference. RTC_Base *globalBase = NULL;
Later: globalBase = new Derived;
Just be sure that you call 'delete' on globalBase, since you are dynamically allocating memory. ('delete' everything you 'new')

Comment: I'm actually doing this on arduino, so it seems a little different, but that got me much closer. And I probably don't really have to call delete since this object exists for as long as the controller is running :P